# TeleBot Error code: 400 при отправке /start

Tags: python, telebot

Пишу бота на пайтоне в телеграм. Выдает ошибку 400, когда самому боту отправить команду `/start`:

```
ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: can't parse entities: Can't find end tag corresponding to start tag b"
```

Comment: Добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (кнопка [edit])

Answer (score 7):

Данная ошибка возникает если вы используете `parse_mode='HTML'` и не закрыли тег.

Данный пример завершится с ошибкой:

`bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Извольте <b>выбрать', parse_mode='HTML')`

> Bad Request: can't parse entities: Can't find end tag corresponding to start tag b"

- не закрыт тег `<b>`

Верный пример:

`bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Извольте <b>выбрать</b>', parse_mode='HTML')`

- Тег `<b>` закрыт. (`</b>`)