# Error Code: 400 unsupported parse_mode, хотя тег закрыт

Tags: python, telebot

Возможно, дубль, но у меня, в отличие от [оригинала](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1234713/telebot-error-code-400-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-start) тег закрыт. Дело в том, что когда я нажимаю на кнопку бота Telegram (код предоставлю ниже) появляется вот такая ошибка:

```
(__init__.py:652 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: unsupported parse_mode"
```

Сам код кнопки:

```
    elif message.text == "McAfee 1 год":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Хороший выбор! McAfee 1 год стоит ",mcafee_price," рублей\nОписание: McAfee - это хороший антивирус, который сможет защитить как ваши мобильные устройства так и ваш ПК. У нас вы смоежете приобрести этот антивирус на один год и с безлимитным подключением устройств всего за ",mcafee_price," деревянных!")
```

У кнопки было вообще другое название изначально и все хорошо работало. Другие кнопки вполне хорошо работают.

Сам код, где храниться parse_mode:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот для покупки софта, игр и различных подписок на разные сервисы".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),parse_mode='html',reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: А такая запись разве верна `{1.first_name} ` и `{0.first_name} `? Может правильней так `{1}` и `{0}`, а в format `(message.from_user.first_name, bot.get_me().first_name)`. Также попробуйте убрать `first_name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы в функцию отправки сообщения через запятую передаёте аргументы. Правильно так:

```py
text = f"Хороший выбор! McAfee 1 год стоит {mcafee_price} рублей\n" \
       f"Описание: McAfee - это хороший антивирус, который сможет защитить как ваши " \
       f"мобильные устройства так и ваш ПК. У нас вы смоежете приобрести этот антивирус на " \
       f"один год и с безлимитным подключением устройств всего за {mcafee_price} деревянных!"
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)
```